# Can you call a class in a visual studio website project from a class library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, vs-web-site-project

I'm creating a new VS2015 web application, but there's one piece that requires some reporting that already exists in another system.

The other system is a VS2013 solution that has a website (not web application) as it's main project, along with a number of class libraries.  But the website directly contains a bunch of classes that do reporting and other things, and I would rather use those than recreate all the (very complicated) code.

Is there any way to reference the classes in the website from another project or class library?  It's a rather large old application I'm maintaining, and I'd rather not try extracting all that functionality into it's own class library if I don't have to.

If those classes were already in a separate class library, I could reference them easy enough, but unfortunately they are right in the website, and I can't find any information about being able to link to it (presumably because you can't).

Here's a sample structure:

```
MySolution
    MyNewClassLibrary
        MyClass
        {
            MyReportFunction()
            {
                var x = new ReportClass();  // From website project
                x.CreateReportFunction();
            }
        }

OldSolution
    WebsiteProject
        ReportClass
        {
            CreateReportFunction()
            {
                // All the code I'd like to access
            ]
        }
```

Is this possible?  Or do I have a lot of rewriting to do?  Or would looking into converting the website into a web application be a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else is looking for something like this, the answer is no, it's not possible.

I ended up pulling all the functionality out into a new class library project, which required massive testing to make sure I got all the little bits and pieces right.

Moral of the story - build your software properly the first time, and pull functionality out into reusable objects.  Don't do procedural programming in an object-oriented language.

Answer (score 1):

You can add those existing classes as linked classes into your solution.

To add an existing item to a project

1. In Solution Explorer, select a target project.
2. On the Project menu, select Add Existing Item.
3. In the Add Existing Item dialog box, locate and select the project item you want to add.
4. From the Open button drop-down list, select Add As Link.

[image]

You can also read more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Would those linked classes lose all the references from the website project?  I didn't mention it, but they call into the class libraries the website uses.  The classes I want aren't completely self-contained.

Comment: Then you might want to add required references of class libraries into your new project as well. Is that a problem?

Comment: That's part of the complication I'm trying to avoid.  There are dozens of classes with dozens of references.  I'd rather just be able to call the existing code and not have to do that.  I might be dreaming though...

Comment: If this is about few classes and one time requirement, then you should do. If this is about whole project and can be re-used in future as well then you could extract those classes into a new class library, add required references, then refer new class library into your projects which definitely require some effort

Comment: I'm fine with that, it's the client who has to pay me that doesn't care so much for the idea  :)